# In Indian ITR e filing, can I include the advance amount for rent declaration?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, tax-deduction

I'm trying to submit an ITR efiling for fY 21-22.
I have rented a house from March to December 2022 with rent at 10500.
I then moved to another house from January and am still residing in that house with rent at 12500.

In the mean time, my old owner returned my advance amount 26500 in January 2022.
Also I have paid, 25000 advance to new owner in December 2022

So, while ITR efiling do I need to include the advance amount? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Your old owner returned you 26500 which you had given him as security deposit. Its your own money. It is not an income for you. Hence, there is no need to show it in ITR.